how I can collect the NFT from "off-curve address"?
I bought some NFT from NFT game founders. However, we don't know why but NFT that I bought seems to be transferred to "off-curve address". What I want to know is how I can recover the NFT from that address and how the NFT got to the "off-curve address" address.
